# How to reopen buffer in vim?

Tags: vim

I had some issues with XPTemplate vim plugin. Sometimes it yields with errors, and makes impossible to edit file. I heal it by doing following steps:

1. Delete buffer
2. Find closed file
3. Open file again

How can I automate this process?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on the situation, a forced reload via `:edit!` may already be enough. Otherwise, you could try `:bdelete | edit #`.

I would also inform the plugin author, if you suspect it's due to a bug in the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks for `:e #` -- I just accidentally closed a buffer, and that's just what I needed!